# Php Laravel composer install on composer on a new script

Tags: php, laravel

```
Class MercadoPago\RecuperableError located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Generic/RecuperableError.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\ErrorCause located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Generic/ErrorCause.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\SearchResultsArray located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Generic/SearchResultsArray.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Card located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Card.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\InstoreOrder located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/InstoreOrder.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Subscription located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Subscription.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Refund located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Refund.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\AuthorizedPayment located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/AuthorizedPayment.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Preference located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Preference.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\CardToken located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/CardToken.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\OAuth located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/OAuth.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\DiscountCampaign located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/DiscountCampaign.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Preapproval located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Preapproval.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\PaymentMethod located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/PaymentMethod.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\TrackValues located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/TrackValues.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Documentation located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/Documentation.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Track located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/Track.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Payment located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/Payment.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Tax located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/Tax.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Payer located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/Payer.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Item located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/Item.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Customer located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Customer.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Invoice located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Invoice.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\POS located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/POS.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\AdvancedPayments\Refund located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/AdvancedPayments/Refund.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\AdvancedPayments\AdvancedPayment located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/AdvancedPayments/AdvancedPayment.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\AdvancedPayments\DisbursementRefund located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/AdvancedPayments/DisbursementRefund.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Chargeback located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Chargeback.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Plan located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Plan.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Shipments located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shipments.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\MerchantOrder located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/MerchantOrder.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\MercadopagoSdkTest located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/tests/MercadoPagoSdkTest.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\PaymentMethod located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/PaymentMethod.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\TrackValues located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/TrackValues.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Documentation located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/Documentation.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Track located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/Track.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Payment located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/Payment.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Tax located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/Tax.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Payer located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/Payer.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Item located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/Item.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Components\Payment\IyzicoResponse located in ./app/paygate/Components/Payment/IyzicoResponse.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Components\Payment\RavepayResponse located in ./app/paygate/Components/Payment/RavepayResponse.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Components\Payment\PaypalIpnResponse located in ./app/paygate/Components/Payment/PaypalIpnResponse.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Components\Payment\PagseguroResponse located in ./app/paygate/Components/Payment/PagseguroResponse.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Components\Payment\PaystackResponse located in ./app/paygate/Components/Payment/PaystackResponse.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Components\Payment\RazorpayResponse located in ./app/paygate/Components/Payment/RazorpayResponse.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Components\Payment\MercadopagoResponse located in ./app/paygate/Components/Payment/MercadopagoResponse.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Components\Payment\PayUmoneyResponse located in ./app/paygate/Components/Payment/PayUmoneyResponse.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Components\Payment\PaytmResponse located in ./app/paygate/Components/Payment/PaytmResponse.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Components\Payment\InstamojoResponse located in ./app/paygate/Components/Payment/InstamojoResponse.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Components\Payment\StripeResponse located in ./app/paygate/Components/Payment/StripeResponse.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Components\Payment\PaymentProcess located in ./app/paygate/Components/Payment/PaymentProcess.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Components\Payment\CoingateResponse located in ./app/paygate/Components/Payment/CoingateResponse.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Components\Payment\MollieResponse located in ./app/paygate/Components/Payment/MollieResponse.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Service\MollieService located in ./app/paygate/Service/MollieService.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Service\RavepayService located in ./app/paygate/Service/RavepayService.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Service\MercadopagoService located in ./app/paygate/Service/MercadopagoService.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Service\StripeService located in ./app/paygate/Service/StripeService.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Service\PagseguroService located in ./app/paygate/Service/PagseguroService.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Service\AuthorizeNetService located in ./app/paygate/Service/AuthorizeNetService.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Service\PaypalCheckOutService located in ./app/paygate/Service/PaypalCheckOutService.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Service\PayUmoneyService located in ./app/paygate/Service/PayUmoneyService.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Service\PaytmService located in ./app/paygate/Service/PaytmService.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Service\IyzicoService located in ./app/paygate/Service/IyzicoService.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Service\CoinGateService located in ./app/paygate/Service/CoinGateService.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Service\PaystackService located in ./app/paygate/Service/PaystackService.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Service\InstamojoService located in ./app/paygate/Service/InstamojoService.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Service\PaypalService located in ./app/paygate/Service/PaypalService.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Service\RazorpayService located in ./app/paygate/Service/RazorpayService.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Models\AstrologerModel\WithDrawRequest located in ./app/Models/AstrologerModel/WithdrawRequest.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Http\Controllers\DarkModeController located in ./app/Http/Controllers/Admin/DarkModeController.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Http\Controllers\ColorSchemeController located in ./app/Http/Controllers/Admin/ColorSchemeController.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Http\Controllers\Astrologer located in ./app/Http/Controllers/Admin/Astrologer.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Http\Controllers\API\User\PaymentController located in ./app/Http/Controllers/API/User/PaymentController_20240122.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Http\Controllers\API\User\ChatRequestController located in ./app/Http/Controllers/API/User/ChatRequestController_20240104.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Http\Controllers\API\User\CallRequestController located in ./app/Http/Controllers/API/User/CallRequestController_20240101.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Http\Controllers\API\User\KundaliController located in ./app/Http/Controllers/API/User/KundaliController_20240109.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Http\Controllers\API\User\UserReviewController located in ./app/Http/Controllers/API/Astrologer/UserReviewController.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Http\Controllers\API\Astrologer\WithDrawController located in ./app/Http/Controllers/API/Astrologer/WithDrawController_20240401.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Http\Controllers\API\API\Astrologer\WalletController located in ./app/Http/Controllers/API/Astrologer/WalletController.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Services\AccessToken located in ./app/services/AccessToken.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Services\RtmTokenBuilder located in ./app/services/RtmTokenBuilder.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Services\FCMService located in ./app/services/FCMService.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

In UrlGenerator.php line 121:
                                                                                                                                        
  Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::__construct(): Argument #2 ($request) must be of type Illuminate\Http\Request, null given, called i  
  n /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/a-backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RoutingServiceProvider.php on line 67  
         
                                                                                                                                        

Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

Getting the above error as the php version is 8.1 and getting this error.

Comment: So, for all your `Class App\XXXX\YYYY` error, you have basic errors, for example `App\Http\Controllers\Astrologer` is on `./app/Http/Controllers/Admin/Astrologer.php`, it should be on `./app/Http/Controllers/Astrologer.php` or the namespace should be `App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Astrologer`... So, all the other `App` namespace errors, is the same, it must exactly match the folder and file name (except `app`, it has to be `App` namespace = `app` folder name CASE SENSITIVE). About MercadoPago, I have no idea about the package you are using, but looks like it is out of your control in that case

Comment: the same with service and components too